# Ubuntu SDK on Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, ubuntu-touch, application-development, ubuntu-sdk

I plan to switch from Windows to Linux long term. I just installed my first Kubuntu (since I like Qt) system in a VirtualBox VM hosted in Windows to get familiar with that system (and Linux in general).

I am  developer and intended to look into Ubuntu-Phone development and I would like to try out the corresponding [emulator](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/apps/sdk/tutorials/using-the-ubuntu-emulator/). The website says I should install the Ubuntu [SDK](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-sdk/installing-the-sdk/). Immediately the first beginner's questions arose (sorry, I think they are pretty stupid):

1. Is there any problem or disadvantage when installing the Ubuntu-SDK on a Kubuntu system (instead on Ubuntu) for developing Ubuntu-Phone software?
2. I found command lines that allow to install the Ubuntu SDK. However I first tried to find the SDK using the packet manager called "Muon". I could not find it there. What is the reason that I could not find the SDK in Muon?
3. What about developing native desktop software? Are there separate SDKs for Kubuntu and Ubuntu?
4. Will there ever be a Kubuntu-Phone system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Ubuntu has additional QML library: qt-components-ubuntu. There were some dependencies on Unity long time ago. But it should be ok now. I think that it is not very hard to run SDK even on something like Mac OS (don't know about emulators...).
2. No idea.
3. There is no significant difference between desktop and mobile. For mobile there is just a cross-compiler and additional packaging step. And an ARM executable for the mobile can be directly run on the desktop if `qemu-user-static` is installed.
4. For that we need to teach KDE to morph between desktop and mobile interfaces and port it to Mir.